# Axios Interceptor Response Token Refresh API called but getting Token is expired regardless in refreshToken API & lator all APIs

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor, refresh-token

my axios interceptor is:-

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response, error) => {
  const originalRequest = response.config;

  if (response.data.status === 'Token is Expired' && originalRequest.url === '/api/refresh') {
    this.props.history.push('/logout');
    Promise.reject(error);
  }

  if (response.data.status === 'Token is Expired' && !originalRequest._retry) {
    originalRequest._retry = true;
    const playerToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    return axios
      .get('/api/refresh', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `bearer ${playerToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('from refreshtoken', res);
        const stringRes = JSON.stringify(res);
        const parsedRes = JSON.parse(stringRes);
        const stringData = JSON.stringify(parsedRes.data);
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(stringData);
        const stringToken = JSON.stringify(parsedData.data);
        const parsedToken = JSON.parse(stringToken);

        if (parsedData.success == true) {
          localStorage.setItem('accessToken', playerToken);
          axios.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = `bearer ${parsedToken}`;
          return Promise.resolve();

          return axios(originalRequest);
        } else {
          this.props.history.push('/logout');
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('from refreshtoken', err);
      });
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

My code is running but when my refresh token API is called first time, It also returns the same status "Token is expired" due to which i am logged out of the app. This is happening only in interceptor. When i am calling Refresh API outside of interceptor, it returns with a refresh token.

Does my code have mistakes? or it is some other coding fault entirely.
Please answer & tell me the right way to do it & where do i place my interceptor??
Currently it is placed in a Component which is called just after login.

Comment: MisTyped: localStorage.setItem('accessToken', parsedToken);

Answer (score 0):

Usually the flow should be as such:

1. making a regular request with `accessToken`
2. request fails with status code 401
3. axios interceptor catches it and makes request to `token/refresh`. from that response it gets a new access token.
4. retries the original request.

So the code should looks like this (this is a working example from my app):

```
function isUnAuthorizedError(error) {
  return error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401;
}

function shouldRetry(config) {
  return config.retries.count < 3;
}

function updateAuthToken(response) {
  localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
}

async function authInterceptor(error) {
  error.config.retries = error.config.retries || {
    count: 0,
  };

  if (isUnAuthorizedError(error) && shouldRetry(error.config)) {
    const response = await axios.post(`/token/refresh`, {});

    updateAuthToken(response);

    error.config.retries.count += 1;
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.accessToken}`; // update the accessToken
    return axios.rawRequest(error.config); // retries the original request
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
}

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, authInterceptor); // This indicates that authInterceptor will work only on request errors (status code >= 400)
```

Hopes this flow makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you. I've done it already. Still got the same response.

Comment: Thank You. I've understood your code. I have tried to do the same thing. Will try to implement in this way. Lets see what response i'll get.

Comment: Also Can you tell me where do you placed this code in your app. I am new to axios interceptors & from what i gather so far you have to call them once in your app & it'll work in the whole app. but once i refresh the page, my interceptor stops working?

Comment: Correct, each page refresh should config the interceptor.
You can create a file where you are creating a new instance of axios and export that instance. all of your app will use this instance instead of the lib directly. There you can configure your interceptors and base url of the api and such...

Comment: The problem was basically from the backend regarding Refresh token expiry. Thank you for your help.