# How should I store the access token to my API in the browser after login flow authorization

Tags: laravel, oauth, access-token, next.js, laravel-passport

In creating a web app I'm keeping my web client and backend API completely separate. My Laravel API backend will exist on `api.myawesomeapp.com` and my NextJS front end will be the main consumer on `myawesomeapp.com`. laravel Oauth flow uses passport, which works from an API client such as Postman, however I am curious the best way to store my authorization token in the browser to send along for authorized requests.

I have read that keeping it in local storage is not 100% secure so am looking into alternatives. It would seem that a cookie would work, but I would assume that I cannot mark it `httpOnly` is it needs to be sent via the JS. Additionally I am curious *how* I should encrypt it to store it in the browser, I am skeptical of rolling my own, curious how I should approach this if this is in fact the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Save it in memory (in a variable), and attach it with each request.

If your `accessToken` is **expired** or the user **refreshed the browser** (therefore the in memory accessToken flushed) make a request to `api/refresh` to get a new `accessToken`.

Checkout this flow, [Axios Interceptor Response Token Refresh API called but getting Token is expired regardless in refreshToken API & lator all APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909095/axios-interceptor-response-token-refresh-api-called-but-getting-token-is-expired/58910164#answer-58910164)