# Reactjs persist jwt token in client side after authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, axios, persistent-storage

I am using JWT token for authentication, so when I send an authentication request the server respond with two Token `Refresh Token` and `Access Token` 
the `Refresh Token` is saved on local storage and the `Access Token` on `Redux Store` 
so with every refresh to the app (request from the url tab) the Access token in the Redux is set to empty so in the main Component `APP.js` I send this request to retrieve it using the `Refresh Token`

```
const refTok = localStorage.getItem('refTok')
useEffect(() => {

        axios.post("http://localhost:9000/api/refresh-token", { refTok : refTok})
         .then( res => {
          if(res.data.err) {    
              console.log(res.data.err)       
            } else {
              props.dispatch(setToken(res.data.acsTok))   
            }
          })    
    }, [])
```

so I use this token to grant Access to other component  if the user is not logged  I redirect him to the home page `history.push('/')`
However the problem with this implementation is that when I try to access a component directly from the URL (for example in case of bookmaked URL ) even if I already logged in the token is reset to empty and the user is immediately pushed to the login page even before the Axios request is done>

any suggestion on how to solve this to persist the value of the Access token , I am trying to avoid saving the `access token` on localStorage

Comment: It looks like a good use case to start digging up the component called [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Comment: Checkout this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909095/axios-interceptor-response-token-refresh-api-called-but-getting-token-is-expired/58910164?noredirect=1#answer-58910164

Comment: basically each page reload, your app won't have accessToken, therefore, the first request will rejected with 401, then axios middleWare will refresh the token using refreshToken, and store it inside the middle ware, if the refreshToken is failed that means that the user is not loggedin, redirect him to `Login` page

Comment: @milkersarac thank you for your advice I will try to implement it

Comment: @felixmosh  I am using your method , it is working fine , the only ppart I couldn't understand and I did not find any documentation for ir is axios.rawRequest could you please help me on how it works

Comment: axios rawRequest is a function that gets an axios request object and makes from it a http request.