# Where can I store my JWT token in client side?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization

We have some options such as localStorage, cookies, in-browser memory to store our JWT, I am also aware that localStorage is vulnerable to XSS, and httpOnly cookies are vulnerable to CSRF and it will be lost on reload/refresh when JWT is placed in the browser.
I studied about the latter issue and come to the solution that putting Refresh Token in httpOnly cookie and access token in browser memory can save me to some degree.
But according to my use case, I have an Admin dashboard from which only authenticated person(basically admin) can make authorised API call. Also, in my WebApp we don't have user input field(text field), So I guess XSS and CSRF hard to attack. So, Can I put JWT Token in httpOnly cookie with expiry of long duration?
Is this a good solution for my use case?

Comment: As you've wrote, it is better to save a refresh token in a httpOnly cookie, and access token in the memory. Other solutions are vulnerable.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909095/axios-interceptor-response-token-refresh-api-called-but-getting-token-is-expired/58910164#answer-58910164

Comment: But we use refresh token to get new access token at the time of expiry but what if I put expiry for longer duration, let say for a day!

Comment: AccessToken with a long duration is very dangerous, think that someone get an accessToken by any method (even physical access to the computer), you won't be able the decline it from you server, because it is a valid & signed token.

Comment: Agreed! 
Take a hypothetical situation where someone cannot get accessToken physically from a computer, in that case is it okay to use my approach?

Comment: It is ok to do what ever you want :], the question is this approach is secure, since it is not the best practice it is less secure.

Comment: Got it! And its a great coincidence academind have uploading the video on same issue today! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBd-SMPp3kI
In short, he suggest to sanitise the user input first to be save from XSS and CSRF.
BTW @felixmosh thanks for replying!

Comment: "Sanitize user input" - is a hard task, if it was easy there was no xss attacks :]